# How to restrict the click on a href link based on checkbox condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to restrict the click on a href link based on checkbox condition(Link should work only if checked)?

```
<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="' . $row['id'] . '"'.($row['pr'] == ""?"disabled ":"").' style="cursor:pointer;" class="checkbox"></td>

<a class="button" href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();" onclick="f1.action='editpr.php'; return true;">
<span><b>Edit Purchase Request</b></span></a>

<a class="button" href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();"><span><b>Remove Purchase Request</b></span></a>
```

I'm really having trouble with this. Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inlined click handlers in favor of a jQuery click handler then in the handler check for the condition

```
<a class="button submit"><span><b>Edit Purchase Request</b></span></a>
<a class="button remove"><span><b>Remove Purchase Request</b></span></a>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a.button.submit, a.button.remove').click(function () {
        if ($('input[name="checkbox[]"]:checked').length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        var frm = document.f1;
        if($(this).hasClass('submit')){
            frm.action = 'editpr.php';
        }
        frm.submit();
    })
})
```

Note: Looks like all the checkbox elements have the id `checkbox[]`, that is not allowed as id of an element must be unique

Comment: the problem is I need the checkbox[] on my php process.

Comment: @papaosurname so... it should work... I hope `f1` is the name of the form containing the checkboxes

Comment: @papaosurname if it is related to a different problem then it will be better to ask a new question.... then you can post a link here so...

Comment: this is my new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113113/checking-the-checkbox-even-i-set-it-into-disabled

Comment: this related with this question, I have another link <a class="button" href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();"><span><b>Remove Purchase Request</b></span></a> would you mine to add this with the script?

Comment: @papaosurname do you want to do the validation when remove is clicked

Comment: just like the first link, restrict the click on a href link if there's no check in checkbox, but the new link post with the same page not in editpr.php

Comment: there is problem, when I try to delete records it's failed. I think I should have name="remove" in my link. I need to post the name of the link to do the remove process

Comment: you can create a hidden field and set its value to `remove`

Answer (score 0):

Here is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bKzDd/)

```
//This is for set the href on page load
settingHref();
//This is for set the herf on chage of checkbox
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
    settingHref();
});
function settingHref() {
    if ($('#checkbox').is(":checked")) {
        $('.button').attr('href', 'javascript:document.forms[0].submit();');
    }
    else {
        $('.button').attr('href', 'javascript: void(0)');
    }
}
```