# Checking the checkbox even I set it into disabled

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

Why even I set the checkbox into disable it always check all when I click the script of check all.

Here's my script

Disable checkbox set by php code

```
 while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="' . $row['id'] . '"'.($row['pr'] == ""?"disabled ":"").' class="checkbox"></td>
}
```

And here's my script on check all

```
function setCheckboxes3(act) {
  var e = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
  var elts_cnt  = (typeof(e.length) != 'undefined') ? e.length : 0;
  if (!elts_cnt) {
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < elts_cnt; i++) {
    e[i].checked = (act == 1 || act == 0) ? act : (e[i].checked ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Links

```
a href="javascript:setCheckboxes3(1);" class="chkmenu">Check All</a> | <a href="javascript:setCheckboxes3(0);" class="chkmenu">Uncheck All</a>
```

Comment: [`document.getElementsByClassName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyclassname) returns a NodeList, therefore `typeof e.length` will never be `undefined`.

Comment: Why include a jQuery tag when you don't seem to be using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the links to pass `true|false`

```
<a href="javascript:setCheckboxes3(true);" class="chkmenu">Check All</a> | <a href="javascript:setCheckboxes3(false);" class="chkmenu">Uncheck All</a>
```

then

```
function setCheckboxes3(act) {
    $('.checkbox').not(':disabled').prop('checked', act)
    //or $('.checkbox:not(:disabled)').prop('checked', act)
}
```

with your current links

```
function setCheckboxes3(act) {
    $('.checkbox').not(':disabled').prop('checked', act == 1 ? true : false);
    //or $('.checkbox:not(:disabled)').prop('checked', act == 1 ? true : false)
}
```

Comment: so I'm going to changed my script with that?

Comment: it works :) , i just add some link with my previous question. Please look at it

Comment: you can do `x.prop('checked', act==1)` or something more crazy like `!~-act`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's messy but it should get the job done:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elts_cnt; i++) {
    if(!e[i].disabled){
    e[i].checked = (act == 1 || act == 0) ? act : (e[i].checked ? 0 : 1);
    }else{
    e[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check it if it's not disabled, something like:

```
e[i].checked = (act == 1 || act == 0)? act : e[i].checked  && !e[i].disabled ? false : true;
```

The checked property is boolean, so it should be set it to `true` or `false`